# DIV content exceeding parent's width

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with some text overflowing outside the parent's div. I tried with

```
element.style {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

but to no avail.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/d2apttt0/) is a JSFiddle with my code. Looks like the DD element goes outside the div. How can I force it inside without specifying a fixed width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<dd>` element has no width to overflow from.

See this updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d2apttt0/1/).

**UPDATE**

Looks like `display:table-cell` was causing the issue in this case. Removing this style and setting `display:flex;` to the parent wrapper fixes the problem.

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7hmy3h4d/2/).

Flexbox is good for dynamic content and responsive design, whereas `display:table-cell;` seems to get stuck at a static width.

Comment: This way you are forcing the <dd> to have a fixed width independently on the page size. The page uses responsive design to adapt to different screen sizes: fixed widths are not an option.

Comment: Then set the width to a %. You say it is overflowing... overflowing from what if nothing has width? You have to have dimensions in order for overflow:hidden to work. Without a width how does it know when it's overflowing?

Comment: Open the JSFiddle link and resize the result window. The email address gets out of the blue panel. This doesn't happen if I remove display: table-cell. But I need that to keep the image (missing in the example) and the data on the same line.

Comment: Then set `overflow:hidden;` on your wrapping div `.c-contact-details`. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bb7of915/)

Comment: Well then in your case the `display:table-cell;` is what is getting you. You can use flexbox to get the result you want. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7hmy3h4d/2/)